# match 2 dictionary with python and check both key and value

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I am matching 2 dictionaries with their keys and values but after
giving it same items the output is coming false, I have to check it
both key and value and if its true it should print true or givr the
matching key and value, I am trying many solutions but unable to get
the results, I need some suggestions and explanations since I am new
in dictionary python, Thanks in advance

```
   first_dict  ={'a':['apple']} 
   second_dict ={'a':['apple','banana'],'b':['mango','orange']}
```

> ```
> ##first solution which I have tried
>  val= all(first_dict[k] == v for k, v in second_dict.items() if k in first_dict)
>  print(val)   ## this is always coming false,
>
> ##second solution which I have tried
> ##even I have try this:
>
> for key,value in set(second_dict.items()) and set(first_dict.items()) 
>  print("the items are",key,value)
> ```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what do you mean by matching dictionaries ? You want to keep entries that are available in both dicts ?

Comment: `second_dict ={['a':'apple','b':'banana']}` is invalid syntax. Are you sure you pasted the correct code?

Comment: The value of 'a' is different in each dict. 'a' in the first dickt is a list. It is a string in the second dict. In fact second_dict isn't even a valid dict.

Comment: I am really sorrs this is my first time And I was confused while writing, Thanks alot for help

Comment: @GaëtanLF so I need to check the entry which is coming from first_dict will be present in the second_dict and if yes then it should print matching key and value, Like in the above case key : a and value:apple